# ARMA model estimation with very distant MA lags won't finish (Python pydse)

Tags: estimation, python, arima, large-data

I have a restricted ARMA(24029,24029) model with lags 6969, 14332 and 24029 (all lags with both an AR and MA term).
I have the following code that I run in python:

```
from pydse.arma import ARMA
ar=numpy.zeros(25000)
ar[6969]=0.01
ar[14332]=0.01
ar[24029]=0.01
ar[0]=1
AR = (ar,numpy.array([25000,1,1]))
MA = (ar,numpy.array([25000,1,1]))

arma = ARMA(A=AR, B=MA, rand_state=0)

arma.est_params(vector)
```

Where vector is length 360 702 vector in this case.

My laptop has been calculating the model for days, even though there are only 6 parameters + constants. Seems like it should complete in seconds.

How can I make the solution process faster? And also, how can I omit the constant from the model, I am 100% certain that there is no constant in the modelling problem I have. Python puts out "Matrix singular" error if I try to omit it (ie. have `ar[0]=0`).

Comment: What is the model (for those not used to reading Python code)?

Comment: @RichardHardy It's an AR/MA model with lags 6969, 14332 and 24029 (all lags with both an AR and MA term). The "vector" is the dependent variable. It's a single variable model...

Comment: Your question title is wrong. It says AR model. AR models should not have convergence issues. It's MA part that may cause issues in this regard

Comment: Look at Rob J. Hyndman's blog posts on modelling time series with long seasonal periods. While yours is not a SARIMA model, the logic still applies.